# Вопрос по MVC, java, swing в одном флаконе

Tags: java, mvc, swing

1. Есть смысл GUI строить в деревообразном стиле(мейнкласс в нем ссылки на пару других классов в которых реализовано гуи панели, и так далее 2-3 уровня в глубину?
2. В GUI в одном из классов вызывается окно, в котором происходит какой то выбор информации(модель данных), как передать всем панелям GUI информацию об этом действии(желательно с примером, ибо в теории все понимаю а на практики непонятно). спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте EventBus, например из Google Guava https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained